# Finding Pythagorean Triple that sums to 1000

Tags: python, programming-challenge

I am doing this [Project Euler Question #9](https://projecteuler.net/problem=9):

> A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, \$a < b < c\$, for which,
>
> $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$
>
> For example, \$3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5^2\$.
>
> There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which \$a + b + c =
> > 1000\$.
>   Find the product \$abc\$.

I have implemented the code but I feel like it runs slow and doesn't perform well enough:

```
def check_pathagorean(a, b, c):
    return (a**2) + (b**2) == (c**2)

SUM = 1000

for i in range(1, SUM):
    for j in range(i+1, SUM):
        c = SUM - (i + j)
        if(check_pathagorean(i, j, c)):
            if i + j + c == SUM:
                print i * j * c
                break
```

What could I do to make this run faster and better?

Comment: You might want to look up Berggren's algorithm to generate the Pythagorean triples.

Comment: You mean =1000 not >=1000

Answer (score 5):

[Any pythagorean triple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) is in form of

> $$ k(u^2 - v^2), 2kuv, k(u^2 + v^2) $$

where u, v, and k are positive integers with u > v, u − v odd, and with u and v  coprime. The sum is therefore

> $$ ku(u + 2v) $$

(the restrictions still apply).

Now your job is factor 1000 into 3 terms (not so many ways to do so, 1000 = 5*5*5*2*2*2) and determine if those terms can be represented with u and v being coprime with an odd difference.

Comment: Isn't the sum actually `2*k*u*(u+v)`?

Comment: And `k` does not have to be a positive integer... The solution to this one has `u = 25; v = 15; k = 1/2`.

Comment: It would be useful to add something about whether/how this proposed algorithm would actually improve on the original idea, in terms of speed/complexity.

Comment: @Stuart The proposed algorithm is O(d(n)^2), isn't it obvious?

Comment: Erm, not to me and I suspect not to the OP. What is d? There is a very simple O(n) solution.

Comment: The algorithm is O(1) and reduces to: `print 31875000`

Comment: @Jaime: no, k can be supposed to be an integer greater than 0. Here u=20, v=5, k=10 give the solution.

Comment: @Stuart: d(n) is the number of divisors of n, so for n=1000 the divisors of n are {1,2,4,5,8,10,20,25,40,50,100,125,200,250,500,1000} and d(n)=16.

Comment: @Emanuele Paolini: but your algorithm is hard to extend to n (or SUM in the OP's notation) different from 1000.

Answer (score 4):

1. `if i + j + c == SUM` is not needed as you have already set `c = SUM - (i + j)`
2. When you find the result and `break` out of the inner loop, you are not breaking out of the outer loop, so the programme will continue through all possible values of `i` and `j`. Fix this by putting the loop inside a function and `return`ing the value.
3. Think about the fact that `c` must be larger than `i` and `j`, which reduces the ranges that you have to loop over.
4. However some further algebra reveals that there is no need to loop over `j` at all. This is because you can make `j` the subject of

$$i^2 + j^2 = (SUM - i - j)^2 $$

and calculate a unique solution given `i` and `SUM`. You then just have to check if it is an integer.

This step also allows us to calculate the exact range over which we can loop `i`. Given that `i < j`, the maximum value of `i` turns out to be `1 - sqrt(1/2)` times the `SUM`.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the ratio of a,b,c in a Pythagorean triplet no variable can ever be larger than half the sum of a+b+c therefore I have lowered the upper limit to 500 or SUM/2. Then, as Stuart mentioned, the if i + j + c == SUM is redundant. Finally by using xrange and eliminating the call to another function we have this.

```
def pythagorean():
    for a in xrange(500):
        for b in xrange(a+1,500):
            c=1000-(a+b)
            if a**2+b**2==c**2:
                return a*b*c
```

These changes brought the run time down from 0.119642019272 to 0.0286219120026 seconds

Comment: +1 nice observation. The Both loops are reduces by the factor \$\frac{1}{2}\$ so the whole algorithm is reduced by the factor \$\frac{1}{4}\$