# Project Euler #9 - Pythagorean triplets

Tags: python, optimization, beginner, programming-challenge

This code works, and I'm trying to figure out if there's a better way to optimize it. As you can see, I've cut down drastically on time just by using numbers that work for `a < b < c`. Is there any outstanding thing that can reduce the time? It currently takes ~7 seconds.

**Problem:**

> A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, \$a < b < c\$, for which
>
> $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$
>
> For example, \$3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5^2\$.
>
> There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which \$a + b + c = 1000\$.  Find the product \$abc\$.

**My code:**

```
import time

start = time.time()

def pythag(a, b, c):
    if a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2:
        return True
    return False

a = [x for x in range(1, 1000)]

for num in a:
    for dig in range(num, 1000 - num):
        for i in range(dig, 1000 - dig):
            if num + dig + i == 1000:
                if pythag(num, dig, i):
                    print(num, dig, i)
                    print("Product: {}".format(num * dig * i))
                    elapsed = time.time() - start
                    print("Time: {:.5f} seconds".format(elapsed))
                    exit(1)

# 200 375 425
# Product: 31875000
# Time: 7.63648 seconds
```

Comment: You should take a look at Euclid's Formula, it will be very fast, you can find an explanation at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Comment: @clutton Just read through that. Thank you very much!

Comment: With many of those Euler problems it is just finding the right way to go about it and sometimes the right formula will exist.  You should get well under a second, good luck. :)

Comment: Have you looked here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/finding-pythagorean-triple-that-sums-to-1000? This can be done with a single loop instead of 3.

Comment: This problem can be solved using pencil and paper using [Euklids formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple).

Comment: @miracle173 Yep, but I did it for fun/practice with Python

Comment: @miracle173 as far as I can see this particular problem is much simpler to solve without using Euclid but just by rearranging the algebra in the question.

Comment: @Stuart: if  a,b,c is the triple with a+b+c=s(=1000) and a^2+b^2=c^2 we have to check O(s^3) values for the "(a,b,c) in {1,...s}^3" approach of the OP, and O(s^2) values for the "(a,b) in {1,...s}^2" approach of mleyfman that uses the equation  "a+b+c=s" to calculate c. Your code uses additionally a^2+b^2=c^2 and "(a) in {1,...s}" and so O(s) values are to check. Using the additional assumption a=m^2-n^2, b=2*m*n, c=m^2+n^2 then m is a divisor of s/2 and m<sqrt(s/2). so we have only to check O(sqrt(s)) values or can even perform better if we can factor in a more performant way.

Comment: @miracle173 I still think it's quicker without Euclidean methods - see http://ideone.com/6t0hZA

Comment: @Stuart: I don't think so: http://ideone.com/HIxLgN

Comment: @Stuart: a  comparison can be found  [here](http://ideone.com/diqauf). Even for n=1000 the algorithm is faster by 20%. The program indicates that for n~10000 it is faster by the factor 5-40, for n~100000 it is faster by the factor 50-400. n=7064950394940 takes less than 2 second but I think it cannot be solved with your algorithm

Comment: @Stuart: Thanks for the link to http://ideone.com/ . I did not know this. It is really great.

Comment: @miracle173 yep you're right. Other algorithms I found using Euclid all looked a lot more complicated than that so I wasn't convinced they could be faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without changing your time too much I got these results:

Original run:

```
>>> 
200 375 425
Product: 31875000
Time: 8.19322 seconds
>>>
```

New code:

```
>>> 
200 375 425
Product: 31875000
Time: 0.28517 seconds
>>>
```

What I changed:

- I moved the timing to completely surround the code, instead of when it hit the triplet.
- I inlined the check for the triplet, as functions are slow in Python
- Instead of generating a list for num, I used a range object straight up to generate them as needed
- I eliminated the i loop and condition by using the fact that `i` will need to be `1000 - num - dig`.

---

Resulting code:

```
import time

start = time.time()

for num in range(1, 1000):
    for dig in range(num, 1000 - num):
        i = 1000 - num - dig
        if num * num + dig * dig == i * i
            print(num, dig, i)
            print("Product: {}".format(num * dig * i))

elapsed = time.time() - start               
print("Time: {:.5f} seconds".format(elapsed))
```

Fun fact: the check for a triplet in this case can be reduced to:

```
num * dig + 1000 * i == 500000
```

Where did I get these magic numbers you ask? Math. Check it out:

$$(\text{num}+ \text{dig}+ i)^2 = 1000^2$$
Expand:
$$\text{num}^2 + \text{dig}^2 + i^2 + 2 \; \text{num}  \; \text{dig}+ 2  \; \text{num}  \; i + 2  \; \text{dig}  \; i = 1000000$$
Use triplet equality:
$$2 i^2 + 2  \; \text{num}  \;  \text{dig}+ 2  \; \text{num}  \; i + 2  \; \text{dig}  \; i = 1000000$$

Factor:

$$i(\text{num}+ \text{dig}+ i) + \text{num} \; \text{dig}= 500000$$

Use fact that \$\text{num}+ \text{dig}+ i = 1000\$ in our case:

$$\text{num} \; \text{dig}+ 1000 i = 500000$$

Comment: I like the inline version of triplet check. And yes, changing the `i` to limit it to the only possible value given `num` and `dig` greatly reduces the time (as seen in my latest edit). Thanks!

Comment: Oops, forgot to show that I also did the same thing with removing the list. This is basically super close to the solution I came up with.

Comment: Chose as answer just for that last part, reduces time to 0.115 seconds!

Answer (score 3):

Whilst for triples, it is easy to find the nice formula, in many problems that will not be so easy.

So, as it demonstrates a basic principle, you should have fewer loops and solve for terms where possible.

In this case, remove the loop over `i` and simply set `i = 1000 - num - dig`.

So in fact the extra constraint here is so useful, you may do not require the Euclid, but @clutton's comment suggests that you can use to it go much faster. Note that whilst I can't recall if I used the formula for this problem myself, I'm pretty sure I did find it essential for some other Euler problems.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that (forgot to add to original post), and it reduced the time to 0.27 seconds.

Comment: @Keith - I actually used Euclid's formula for the problem when I did it long ago and it solves in about 1ms which I thought was pretty fast compared to other methods I've seen.  I wouldn't say that it is not a helpful formula for this particular problem.

Comment: @clutton. Fair enough - I'll amend my comment.

Answer (score 3):

### Naming and expressiveness

I found your code hard to read, due to issues with naming and general clumsiness in expression.

For example, your `pythag()` function should be

```
def is_pythagorean_triplet(a, b, c):
    return a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2
```

Next, looking at `if num + dig + i == 1000`, I have to wonder, how did the *a*, *b*, and *c* in the original problem turn into weird variable names `num`, `dig`, and `i`?

```
for a in range(1, 1000):
    for b in range(a, 1000 - a):
        for c in range(b, 1000 - b):
            if a + b + c == 1000:
                if is_pythagorean_triple(a, b, c):
                    print(a, b, c)
                    print("Product: {}".format(a * b * c))
                    exit(0)
```

Now we have an inefficient brute-force solution, but at least it has the virtue of being a very literal translation of the problem into Python.

Note that `exit(1)` was not appropriate.  By convention, a non-zero exit indicates an error.

### Optimization

Without drastically [changing the strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples), we can still make a major improvement.  There is no point in iterating to find `c` such that `a + b + c == 1000`, when you can determine it by simple arithmetic.

```
for a in range(1, 1000):
    for b in range(a, 1000 - a):
        c = 1000 - a - b
        if c < b:
            break
        if is_pythagorean_triple(a, b, c):
            print(a, b, c)
            print("Product: {}".format(a * b * c))
            exit(0)
```

Comment: Yes, the optimization you have mentioned has already been discussed and yields the same result. Nevertheless, I really appreciate a lot of the things you mentioned in the naming and expressiveness section because I am new to the language and all I've been using is a flake 8 lint for ST2. I should've added the beginner tag that I just learned is on this site (there isn't one on SO). Thank you!